# OutlinedTextField, JetPack Compose, Android Studio

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have two promlems with OutlinedTextField:

1. Keyboard don't work on right field
2. What is an echo value in field? How teminate it?
   [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPyBg.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcfGK.jpg)

Comment: Without code it is impossible to help you

Comment: I solved all problem wit TextField)